NestJS & Jest: The presence of jest.config.ts causes "strange behavior" during build
I have a Nestjs service inside my monorepo project with the following structure:
/
- package.json
- packages/
- - frontend/
- - backend/
- - backend/package.json

backend is the nestjs service, everything works fine until i added jest.config.ts
my service makes use of some static files so it relies on the presence of those files in correct location, but the mere presence of jest.config.ts ruins this by changing the structure of the build directory (dist).
before adding jest.config.ts:
/backend
-- dist
-- dist/auth
-- dist/users
-- dist/main.js
-- dist/...

after adding jest.config.ts:
-- dist
-- dist/common
-- dist/src
-- dist/src/main.js

common is compiled to both dist/ and dist/src which is even weirder.
tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["../lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*spec.ts", "**/*jest.config.ts"]
}

jest.config.ts:
import { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.(t|j)s'],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '.*\\.spec\\.ts$',
  rootDir: '.',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/'],
};

export default config;

I've scanned the docs but couldn't find any info of what might cause this, thanks.

This looks like a problem with project / TS configuration. If adding a file (jest.config.ts) somewhere changes the compiler output in the way that you describe, then the compiler probably includes that file in the compilation source. Otherwise, please provide an MRE. I doubt anyone will be able to offer an exact solution without one - the question is just too vague and there aren't enough details.
